# XML Class for the partial file used in a Nokogiri class XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Using rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2.

I am using Nokogiri to build custom XML. I am calling a partial builder file in the main view file. But the class being used in partial for xml is not Nokogiri. Can anyone explain why the xml class is not Nokogiri ?

#### index.xml.erb

```
<%= Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') { |xml|
  puts "xml class in main file #{xml.class}"
  xml.users {
    @users.each do |user|
      xml << render(:partial=>"users/user", :locals=>{:user=>user, :xml => xml})
    end
  }
}.to_xml.html_safe
%>
```

#### _user.builder

```
puts "xml class in builder file #{xml.class}"
xml.user {
  xml.id user.id
  xml.name user.name
  xml.email user.email
}
```

In application.rb, using :

```
ActiveSupport::XmlMini.backend = 'Nokogiri'
```

Output :

```
xml class in main file Nokogiri::XML::Builder
xml class in builder file Builder::XmlMarkup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `ActiveSupport::XmlMini.backend = 'Nokogiri'` is only for parsing XML params with Nokogiri instead of ReXML, not for builder template generation.

You're creating a Nokogiri::XML::Builder manually, then relying on `render` to generate the partial, therefore your output is consistent.

Use the following (in `config/initializers/nokogiri_builders.rb` to actually use `Nokogiri` via render (plus you can stop using `.xml.erb` files to create your own instance of `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` and just use a `.builder` too):

```
# config/initializers/nokogiri_builders.rb
# Using Nokogiri::XML::Builder in lieu of stock pure ruby Builder for Rails builder templates

module Nokogiri
  module XML
    class Builder
      # handle instruct! instead of emitting nonsense tag
      def instruct!(tag, options = {})
        case tag
        when :xml
          @version = options[:version]
          @encoding = options[:encoding]
        else
          raise NotImplementedError(tag.inspect)
        end
      end

      # redefined, to recover what instruct! gave us
      def to_xml(*args)
        if Nokogiri.jruby?
          options = args.first.is_a?(Hash) ? args.shift : {}
          unless options[:save_with]
            options[:save_with] = Node::SaveOptions::AS_BUILDER
          end
          args.insert(0, options)
        end

        if @version || @encoding
          # set options according to what was given previously
          args[0][:version] = @version if @version
          args[0][:encoding] = @encoding if @encoding
          # do emit a declaration
          args[0].delete(:save_with)
        end

        @doc.to_xml(*args)
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActionView
  module Template::Handlers
    class Builder
      # Default format used by Builder.
      class_attribute :default_format
      self.default_format = :xml

      def call(template)
        require_engine
        code = <<-CODE
          builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
            #{template.source}
          end
          # default to not emit a declaration (use instruct! instead)
          save_options = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION
          # default to UTF-8, as it's Rails default encoding
          options = { encoding: 'UTF-8', indent: 2, save_with: save_options }
          self.output_buffer = builder.to_xml(options)
        CODE

        code
      end

      protected

      def require_engine
        @required ||= begin
          require 'nokogiri'
          true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Watch out though, Nokogiri builds a full DOM before generating output with `to_xml`, whereas Builder concatenates strings on the fly. This might or might not be what you want, especially for large data sets. In both cases though, the full final string is resident in memory.